# Как узнать свойства телефона из библиотеки на C?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Имеются в виду те свойства, которые можно посмотреть во вкладке About (модель, производитель и так далее).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключить заголовок `<cutils/properties.h>` и работать со свойствами парой функций

```
int property_get(const char *key, char *value, const char *default_value);
int property_set(const char *key, const char *value);
```

Если в NDK эти функции недоступны, то можно обращаться к свойствам из Java.